# Minimal distance between quadratic function and point

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I have a function or line $R\rightarrow R^n$

$$ y_i = f(x) = {-b_i \pm \sqrt{-4 \cdot a_i\cdot c_i + b_i^2+4\cdot c_i \cdot x}\over 2 \cdot c_i}$$

where the parameter vectors $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}$ are known. For any value x, I will get a n-dimensional point out. (The equation should look familiar, meaning x(y) are quadratic functions.)

I would like to find for an arbitrary point $\mathbf{p}$ the closest point on this line $f$, and its corresponding $x$.

What I did so far was to differentiate the euclidean norm $\Delta = \sum_i (y_i(x) - p_i)^2 $ and setting it to $0$, yielding, after dividing away non-zero terms:

$$2\cdot \sum_i {p_i + {b_i\over 2 \cdot c_i }\over \sqrt{4 \cdot c_i\cdot  x - 4 \cdot a_i\cdot c_i+ b_i^2}} - {1\over2\cdot c_i} \overset{!}{=} 0 $$

Now I'm stuck. Does an analytic solution for finding $x$ exist?

Comment: Can you go farther backwards for us? Why are you interested in solving the quadratics $c_i^2y_i^2+b_iy_i+c_i^{-1}(a_i-x)=0$?

Comment: Well, I am trying to set up a regression model to fit to points. In particular I want the curve to behave quadratically $x = a_i + b_i y_i + c_i y_i^2$, because that is how the points are approximately lying about. For the points I want to fit, I want to minimize the distances from the curve. Did I make a mistake in setting the problem up?

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out, it should be just $c_i$. Note I use $a$ for the constant, not $c$. Imagine for instance the Rosenbrock function in 2d. Consider the center of the valley it describes. In 2d it looks almost like a quadratic function. I want to write down this central valley as a function of the valley floor height.

Comment: we can stick to n=2. If you look at the Rosenbrock function from each dimension i, and take at the minimum over all other dimensions, you get a quadratic-looking function. That describes a curve through the n-dimensional space, right? Everything else is just a deviation from that curve. The point is not so much what I want to fit, or whether it is deterministic (I can explain more what I am doing, but don't get distracted), but: I have this curve constructed (somehow) and how I can get now the minimum distance from it to a point.

Comment: I'm going to delete my comments soon, since they mostly consist of me asking questions; yours do a pretty good job of filling in the details.

Comment: That's ok by me. I might cut down on the unrelated ones too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this has any closed form solution. Here's why. The difficult part of the formula you have is simplifying an expression of the form $\frac1{\sqrt x} + \frac1{\sqrt y} + \frac1{\sqrt z}$, and some additional terms, so that there is a common denominator with no radical in it. Once you get there, you have an expression of the form $\sqrt a + \sqrt b + \sqrt c$, for which there is at least some hope.

However, to get there, you cannot really avoid converting to the expression $\frac{yz\sqrt{x}+xz\sqrt{y}+xy\sqrt{z}}{xyz}$. Similar things work for longer sums than three, but unfortunately, this is where the good luck stops. We multiply both sides by $xyz$ and what we find is that there are degree-three polynomials on each side of the equality sign, in addition to things in square roots. So the smallest polynomial you can hope to have here is degree six.

Furthermore, there is almost no relationship between the coefficients. Yes, it all looks nice and symmetric when we're doing the heuristics, but $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all nontrivially linear in the variable and there are also constant terms floating around out there. Therefore, [Abel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) is going to come in and say that you probably cannot solve this polynomial algebraically.

Sorry about that :(